# Reading data with a date time 11/12/2018 9:14:35 AM in r

Tags: r, datetime

I have many Excel file with the following structure:

```
Id1    Id2    Id3             location visit_time

302974 204822 984000100745974 302 11/12/2018 9:14:35 AM
301722 203821 984000100768722 301 11/12/2018 9:26:26 AM
302984 204821 984000100745984 302 11/12/2018 9:26:27 AM
301736 503076 984000100768736 301 11/12/2018 9:38:43 AM
302512 204771 984000100769512 302 11/12/2018 9:41:29 AM
302510 204810 984000100769510 302 11/12/2018 9:44:23 AM
301514 503084 984000100769514 301 11/12/2018 9:50:38 AM
301720 503083 984000100768720 301 11/12/2018 9:57:25 AM
302510 204810 984000100769510 302 11/12/2018 10:10:15 AM
301722 503152 984000100768722 301 11/12/2018 11:09:38 AM
302970 204807 984000100745970 302 11/12/2018 11:12:47 AM
301508 503079 984000100769508 301 11/12/2018 11:17:56 AM
```

What I want is to be able to read the original visit_time column without having to modify that column in Excel to a format 11/12/2018 11:17:56, that I can easily read and transform in r. I need to save time.
Thanks in advance
GM

Comment: strptime(df$visit_time, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

Comment: I am not sure, but  I am trying to read the data directly from a CSV file. FIP301302R1 <- read_csv("./CSV301-30218-11-11--19-01-11.csv", 
                        col_types = cols(responder = col_character(), 
                                         visit_time = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:$S %p")))

When I use this command to read a CSV I got the following error:  In rbind(names(probs), probs_f) :   number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1). That is obvious because the format in the CSV file is like        11/12/2018 9:14:35 AM

Comment: Why not just read the csv file and transform the column in a separate step?

Comment: That is what I am doing at this moment, but is time-consuming, and I was looking a way to avoid that.

Comment: You don't need to change the original csv. Read the csv as is into r, then apply the command in my first comment. Doesn't take any time at all

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Comment: > FIP301302R1 <- read_csv("C:/Users/gmartinez/Documents/Gonzalo Martinez/R&D/Feed Intake/Nedap Data/CP/Raw Data/G1/CSV301-30218-11-11--19-01-11.csv", 
+                         col_types = cols(responder = col_character(), 
+                         strptime(FIP301302R1$visit_time, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")))
Error: Some `col_types` are not S3 collector objects: 2

Comment: The problem is with the col_types, not with the strptime. Drop that. Also, take the strptime out of the read.csv call.

Comment: `FIP301302R1<-read.csv("C:/Users/gmartinez/Documents/Gonzalo Martinez/R&D/Feed Intake/Nedap Data/CP/Raw Data/G1/CSV301-30218-11-11--19-01-11.csv"); FIP301302R1$visit_time<- strptime(FIP301302R1$visit_time, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")`

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the date/time is also a dat/time-formatted cell/column in excel?
If so: use the `col_types`-argument in the `read_excel`-function from the `readxl`-package to set the column-type of the imported data.

```
df <- readxl::read_excel( "./Map1.xlsx", 
                          col_types = c( rep("numeric", 4), "date" ) )

# A tibble: 12 x 5
#       Id1    Id2     Id3 location visit_time         
#     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl> <dttm>             
#  1 302974 204822 9.84e14      302 2018-12-11 09:14:35
#  2 301722 203821 9.84e14      301 2018-12-11 09:26:26
#  3 302984 204821 9.84e14      302 2018-12-11 09:26:27
#  4 301736 503076 9.84e14      301 2018-12-11 09:38:43
#  5 302512 204771 9.84e14      302 2018-12-11 09:41:29
#  6 302510 204810 9.84e14      302 2018-12-11 09:44:23
#  7 301514 503084 9.84e14      301 2018-12-11 09:50:38
#  8 301720 503083 9.84e14      301 2018-12-11 09:57:25
#  9 302510 204810 9.84e14      302 2018-12-11 10:10:15
# 10 301722 503152 9.84e14      301 2018-12-11 11:09:38
# 11 302970 204807 9.84e14      302 2018-12-11 11:12:47
# 12 301508 503079 9.84e14      301 2018-12-11 11:17:56
```

Comment: No, the file is a CSV file. Sorry, my question was misleading.

Comment: FIP101104R1 <- read_csv("./ppt101-104_2018-10-07_12-14.csv", 
                        col_types = cols(responder = col_character(), 
                                         visit_time = col_datetime(format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")))

Comment: But with this I need to open each CSV file and modify the visit_time column. What I want is be able to read directly the file without to have to modify the visit_time column. Thanks